# "Learn something fast" or "learn something quickly"?

Tags: adverbs

Tell me please if the following sentences mean the same.

> If you want to learn a language **fast**, you have to immerse yourself into the language.
>
> If you want to learn a language **quickly**, you have to immerse yourself into the language.

Comment: Hi Dmytro, you should use "quickly" here because its an "adverb" - it supports the verb ("to learn") and is therefore most appropriate.  Fast is an adjective so its used for describing things (e.g. "the car is fast").

Comment: I was sure "fast" is also and adverb. For example, "he runs really fast."

Comment: On reflection, I think you're right - lets let someone who knows more than I do set us straight!